# Determine if the following series converges or diverges. If it converges determine its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you tell me why my answer is wrong? What do I see: the sequence of partial sums diverges to ∞ and so the series also diverges.
Please tell me which answer is correct and why.
task and my answer in the screenshot

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞   n$$

[task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwGRf.png)

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know, I think you are right, it clearly diverges.
However, some mathematical literature uses the term "divergent" for series that don't have any limit, including infinity, and that one is "convergent to infinity" if you wanna call it that way.
For example, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n}$ would diverge with that definition, and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n}$ would "converge to infinity".

Try writing "convergent, infinity".
That's the only thing I can think of